# Visual Studio 2005 Express Edition license

Tags: visual-studio

I am thinking of using Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 Express Edition for some commercial use. Where to download it. And is it necessary to register it ? Where to register? Thanks in advance... can i deliver my application to users before register ?

Answer (score 2):

Using the express editions is legally okay. I'm using them with my (private) notebook when I'm doing things for my employer.
But there are some disadvantages, e.g. you can't use add-ins like visual assist or FogBugz for VS, ...

Perhaps you're better off with [Bizspark](http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/)

You don't need to register and yes, you can deliver your app any time with no restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Please see: http://www.microsoft.com/express/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to buy license for that, but if you want to register it, it is free and there is an article showing how :

[Instructions for Downloading and Installing Visual C# 2005 Express Edition](http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/ss/vcsharpins_3.htm)

Comment: But can i deliver my application to users before register

Comment: @sandip: yes and you don't habve to register at all. Express editions are really and completely free to use.

Comment: @Sandip : If I am correctly understanding what you mean by registering : yeah you don't need to buy anything at all and paying for nothing, but if you don't register the product, it will expire 30 days later and registration will prevent expiration. But you don't have to pay any thing for that, it is completely free of charge. You an even sell what you are developing with Microsoft Express Tools.